# Why is Logic Pro X showing MIDI chords as various C-chords?

Tags: daw, logic-pro

When inputting an "F" and an "A", Logic Pro X (10.4.1) tells me that the input chord is a "C no 3<sup>6/11</sup>":

[image: F] + 
[image: A] =

[image: C no 3 ^ 6/11]

Where I would expect an "F." This is true for every chord I input; all are showing as either a form of C or of D.

It started immediately after setting up my new Novation LaunchKey Mini Mk3, but is happening even with that device unplugged, using Musical Typing.

Comment: Firstly: Logic is great for recording/sequencing but *terrible* at identifying chords. It’s just not a tool for that; don’t rely on it to correctly identify chords. Secondly: Logic will often try to name a chord in relation to the bass, rather than giving a more sensible interpretation of a chord inversion; is it possible that you have a C sounding at the same time? Maybe in some already recorded part? Maybe even a really low key switch that you can’t hear?

Comment: That seems plausible! There’s no recorded music here, so it’d definitely be part of the input — probably from the Novation. Any thoughts on how I could go about finding the rogue C?

Comment: Hello again. I just checked this with my setup: and yes, I get an F chord. Sorry don't know how to help. At least your problem isn't as bad as the one described at this link: https://www.logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=140441 Might be worth poking around on logicprohelp.com - they have a lot of good questions and answers...

Comment: I did manage to resolve it by pressed A LOT of buttons on my Novation. Unfortunately, that's not a useful answer for anyone else with this problem, so I'm going to leave the question open for now!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with chord display suddenly for no apparent reason showing weird variations of a C chord when Dm, Em etc. triad played. Tried everything I could find on the web, nothing worked. Then tried this from Apple Support page and problem solved! My keyboard is a Novation Impulse49.

Delete the PLIST file for control surfaces
If you use a control surface with Logic Pro, try deleting the PLIST file for control surfaces.
Quit Logic Pro.
In the Finder, choose Go > Go to Folder.
Enter ~/Library/Preferences, then click Go.
Delete the “com.apple.logic.pro.cs” file from the Preferences folder.
Restart your Mac.
Open Logic Pro.
Depending on your control surface, you might need to add the control surface again to use it with Logic Pro.
If you're using Logic Remote, you're prompted to reconnect Logic Remote when you open the Logic Remote app for the first time after deleting the PLIST file.
If you're using a device that supports the EuCon protocol, you don't have to add it within Logic Pro.